# How to put 3D and 2D arrays into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, iteration

I'm having problems with putting 3D and 2D arrays into a dataframe.

- The first array is  (2905, 150, 150);
- The second array is (2905, 3)

I want a dataframe with 2905 rows, in which I have, for each item, 2D (150,150) arrays for column 1 and 1D arrays (3) for column 2.

Working with a smaller example ((3,2,2) for my 3D array and (3,2) for my 2D array) but, with the same intention:

```
a = [[[2,6],[1,95]],[[88,42],[21,90]],[[54,78],[47,70]]]
a = np.array(a)

b = [[1,0],[0,0],[0,1]]
b = np.array(b)
```

[3D (a) and 2D (b) arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3r8j.png)

I want this as a result:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffs67.png)

I wanna find a way I could do this iteratively. Anyone has any ideia?

Thank you so much!

Comment: _I'm having problems with putting 3D and 2D arrays into a dataframe._ What is the problem? Without converting the lists to arrays, `pd.DataFrame({"col_1": a, "col_2": b})` seems to work fine. Also, what do you mean by iteratively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be easily done by

```
pd.DataFrame(zip(a,b))
```

result

```
          0                    1
0   [[2, 6], [1, 95]]       [1, 0]
1   [[88, 42], [21, 90]]    [0, 0]
2   [[54, 78], [47, 70]]    [0, 1]
```